# how to create a user card animation like google maps for iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

In the new google maps for iOS when you search for a place, it has a card on the bottom that you can drag/animate up and down. I am trying to replicate this by using a UIPanGestureRecognizer on a UIViewController's view, however when I flick up I wanted it to animate smoothly like it does on Google Maps. How can achieve this effect? When I tap and hold on it works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the speed that you want it to move at (possibly the speed of the flick, possibly less if that is too fast), then use [animateWithDuration:animations:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration%3aanimations%3a) to animate the view to its final position.  Set the duration such that it moves at the speed you want it to move.